# include_all_form_fields parameter for subfields in laravel backpack

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I want to complicate the question a little from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78092199/filter-the-output-of-a-select2-from-ajax-field-depending-on-another-field-in-cru).
If we have one form, then we can easily process the request in a fetch function. How can we implement the search if we have several identical forms in the subfields?
For example

```
public function setupCreateOperation()
{
    ...
    $this->crud->addFields([
        [
        'name'  => 'anyRows',
        'type'  => 'relationship',
        'label' => 'Table 1-N',
        'subfields'   => [
            [
                'name'    => 'status',
                'label'   => trans($this->trans_prefix . 'status'),
                'type'    => 'select_from_array',
                'options' => [
                    0 => 'one',
                    1 => 'two'
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name'                    => 'service_id',
                'label'                   => trans($this->trans_prefix . 'service'),
                'type'                    => 'select2_from_ajax',
                'entity'                  => 'service',
                'method'                  => 'post',
                'data_source'             => url('fetch/service'),
                'minimum_input_length'    => 0,
                'include_all_form_fields' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

What should we do in this case? So that a fetch request for a service field would depend only on the corresponding status field?
It seems to me that you need to somehow pass the row number in the anyRows array in order to parse the request in the future. Is it possible to do this?

```
public function fetchService($args)
{
    dd($args); // args - number in anyRows array
}
```

Data request now:

```
array:2 [ 
    "q" => ""
    "form" => array:4 [
        0 => array:2 [
          "name" => "anyRows[0][status]"
          "value" => "1"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [
          "name" => "anyRows[0][service]"
          "value" => null <- The collection to select depends on the parameter anyRows[0][status]
        ]
        2 => array:2 [
          "name" => "anyRows[1][status]"
          "value" => "0"
        ]
        3 => array:2 [
          "name" => "anyRows[1][service]"
          "value" => null <- The collection to select depends on the parameter anyRows[1][status]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested something similar and got the subfield's values in the Ajax request:
[image]

I recommend you create a custom API route instead of `fetchOperation` for your case flexibility.
You can find an example here in the demo repo. [link](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/demo/blob/36610772c8c90764e73b6c9fe91ec47184ebf447/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ArticleController.php#L13)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented everything using the select2_ajax custom field. Inside which I pass the line number since the relation is 1-n. Yes, you wrote correctly, we can get ALL the data from the request, but we need to understand the value of the dependent country field.